# Formula Builder Evaluate method Detail

Tags: acumatica

We have string that has formula created by Formula Builder , the fields can be replaces with value dynamically while the evaluation is failed.

can you please give the code used for Evaluate method on formula builder so that the string stored in database can be evaluated with same function to get the numeric value from the formula string.

Comment: Can you post any code examples of what you are trying to do? Also, is this in a report designer, or generic inquiry field?